# Prove that A ... is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would you do this problem: Prove that A has a geometric multiplicity of 1 and does not have a basis of eigenvectors and hence is not diagonalizable.  I know how to find the normal eigenvectors but am not sure about proving this statement.  I also know that geometric multiplicity refers to the maximal number of linear independent eigenvectors?

My matrix is A= $$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 1 &  \\
        0 & 3 & 
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question.

Comment: To solve the problem it suffices to find all eigenvectors and see that they do not generate $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: If you know how to find the eigenvectors, I do not see how you can go wrong. Find them all, and everything should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

proof by contradiction. suppose $A =\pmatrix{3&1\\0&3}$ is digonalisable. then there is an invertible matrix $U$ such that $$A = U\pmatrix{3&0\\0&3}U^{-1}. \tag 1$$ that the diagonal matrix must have $3$'s on the diagonal follows from $A$ and $D$ being similar and similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

from $(1),$ you get $$A - 3I = U \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}U^{-1} = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$$

implying $A = 3I$ contradicting $A =\pmatrix{3&1\\0&3}.$